# HTMLPanel.wrap() assert fails

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm using `UiBinder` to create a custom widget. The UI template is something like:

```
<g:HTMLPanel styleName="setting">
    <div ui:field="dynamicDiv">
    </div>
    {other stuff here}
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Then, to add widget in the `dynamicDiv` I wrap it with HTMLPanel:

```
HTMLPanel.wrap(dynamicDiv);
```

and just use it as a normal widget.

When I run the application normally everything is fine, but if I run in debug mode, the following

```
assert Document.get().getBody().isOrHasChild(element);
```

in `HTMLPanel.wrap()` it fails, hence I am unable to debug the code.

Apart from the annoyance of debugging, I guess there was a good reason to put that assert there, so I would like to understand what is the correct way to wrap that div.

Comment: Well, you can use another widgets that generate a `<div>` like the `SimplePanel` or a `FlowPanel`, I suppose it is easier to workaround this issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to *wrap* the div, just use the appropriate method from the containing `HTMLPanel`; e.g.:

```
theHtmlPanel.add(theWidget, dynamicDiv);
```

Comment: Never noticed that one! Do you know if the element must be a direct child or any descendant of the HTML Panel?

Comment: It has to be a descendant of the panel.